# How to find characters lost in encoding conversion?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

I've had a html file with ISO-8859-2 text encoding.

The charset was manually set to UTF-8.

The characters č ć ž đ š were lost in conversion.

The reason could be the environment change (git to local) [phpStorm].

Further,

The mentioned characters now all relate to the same ascii character - �>ć �>č �>ž

I tried to look up the character on asciivalue.com and I always seem to get "�"

Can't even search&replace because environment flatten characters out to be the same ascii.

---

I think phpStorm environment converted all the unknown characters to the same �

Comment: What is the *binary value* of those characters now? Look at the data with a hex editor and see what the actual bytes are.

Comment: "charset was manually set to UTF-8": what does this mean? What conversion took place? Why do you mention ASCII alongside ISO-8859-2 and UTF-8?